# How do I get csv file of Gmail contacts to import?

Tags: contacts, import

I am trying to import a Google Apps Contacts list in csv file format. I go through the steps; it goes through the motions of importing the file, but no contacts are added.
We're running CiviCrm 4.7.8. It's a trial run on a friend's Wordpress account. We get a System Status:Error message that everything's not configured yet e.g. No Cron Running. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

That cron is not running is not affecting the import process.

Ideas - in no particular order:

- Perhaps your csv needs some formatting? Do you have columns for First Name; Last Name; Email adress and are they all in expect format? Email address should just be email address only (so separate columns):

Mary (in column 1)
Smith (in column 2)
Mary.Smith@example.com (in column 3)

- I find that MS Excel does not always give me a correctly formatted importable CSV file... so I always use Open Office instead - just look and save
- is the upload directory writable by the user the webserver runs as? Not sure where that lives in Wordpress; in Drupal it's files/civicrm/upload

Comment: Thanks for your response, Karin. The columns were all formatted correctly. I tried again and it worked. The only change was that I left the default date format as it was.